# Proper way to add dependencies to gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Please consider the following code

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1

    dependencies {compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.7'
}


dependencies{

        compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.7'

}
```

I want to add that new dependency. What is the proper way to add this?

Comment: Just look at it... There's a dependencies block. You follow the format shown

Comment: thats not my question. Im just looking for a proper example. i dont see it visually

Comment: There's already 3 lines containing exactly `compile 'some:package:x.y.z`... I'm confused how you don't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the Steps

Step 1: Open Project Structure (Ctrl+Alt+ Shift+S)

Step 2: Tap app menu

Step 3: Tap Dependencies option

Step 4: click + menu to add  "library dependency"

Step 5: Type the keywords for your dependency

Step 6: Click Search icon

Step 7: Double Click the dependency that found in Search,

Dependency Added...!

[[image: show case [1]]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.7'` into `dependencies`, like this:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1

    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.7'
}
```

Comment: I know that part but Im not sure which block of code to put this in. I just want to see the right way done. So I know for future use

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about the syntax or where to add the dependencies in gradle files use Android Studio: File -> Project Structure

[image]